Mockito Verification Fails with any(type::class.java) or any() in Kotlin Unit Test
I'm currently writing a unit test in Kotlin using Mockito for a function that saves data to SharedPreferences. I'm trying to verify that a method was called with specific parameters, but I'm encountering an issue when using any(Context::class.java) and any().
Here's the line of code that's causing the problem:
verify(sharedPreferencesProvider, times(1)).saveLong(any(Context::class.java), eq(dataName), anyLong())

This line is supposed to verify that the saveLong method of sharedPreferencesProvider was called exactly once with a Context object, a specific dataName, and any Long value.
However, the verification fails, even though I'm sure that the saveLong method is being called with the correct parameters in the function I'm testing.
I've also tried using just any() instead of any(Context::class.java), but that doesn't seem to work either. It results in a NullPointerException, even though the any() matcher should match any argument, including non-null ones.
Here's the function I'm testing:
fun validateFrequency(data: SplashScreens, gson: Gson, viewModelScope: CoroutineScope): Boolean {
    // ... (code omitted for brevity)

    sharedPreferencesProvider.saveLong(context, "mp_"+ data.name, currentTime)

    // ... (code omitted for brevity)
}

And here's the test case:
@Test
fun `test validateFrequency`() = runTest(testDispatcher) {
    // ... (code omitted for brevity)

    val result = nudgeBottomSheetUtils.validateFrequency(data, gson, this)

    assertTrue(result)

    verify(sharedPreferencesProvider, times(1)).saveLong(any(Context::class.java), eq(dataName), anyLong())

    // ... (code omitted for brevity)
}

Does anyone know why the verification might be failing and how I can fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.


NPE makes me suspect that sharedPreferencesProvider is not a mock, but something else (a real object from your production code or a Mockito.spy). Could you [edit] your question to include how the provider mock is initialized and assigned?

Voting to close; the question is unanswerable without more detail (missing [mre]) and there was no reply from the OP in two weeks.
